# Can WCF REST (WebHttpBinding) honor PROGRAMMATIC outputcache policies?

Tags: wcf, outputcache, wcf-rest, webhttpbinding

I know all about the `AspNetCacheProfileAttribute`. But is there any way to hook into the cache programmatically? I've tried using Response.Cache in global.asax which seems to set the correct client-side headers but the response is never cached on the server.

Comment: What do you mean by programmatically? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to be able to set my cache policy in code instead of in web.config. This will give me much more flexibility at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it unless you build your own solution. I just checked implementation of `AspNetCahceProfileAttribute` which only add internal `CachingParameterInspector` to the operation dispatcher. This has two problems:

- Parameter inspector is assigned when the service host starts = during first request and until that it cannot be changed
- Parameter inspector is initialized in its cosntructor by reading cache configuration from the web.config file based on the profile name passed to `AspNetCacheProfileAttribute`

There is no API available to modify already assigned and configured parameter inspector